# How can I access a graphics card's output directly?

Tags: c, graphics, gpu

Do graphics cards typically write their output to some place in memory which I can access? Do I have to use the driver? If so, can I use OpenGL?

I want to know if it's possible to "capture" the output of a VM on Linux which has direct access to a GPU, and is running Windows. Ideally, I could access the output from memory directly, without touching the GPU, since this code would be able to run on the Linux host.

The other option is to maybe write a Windows driver which reads the output of the GPU and writes it to some place in memory. Then, on the Linux side, a program can read this memory. This seems somewhat impossible, since I'm not really sure how to get a process on the host to share memory with a process on the guest.

Is it possible to do option 1 and simply read the output from memory?

Comment: What do you believe the "output" of a graphics card is?   What you believe is probably wrong.

Comment: A frame. A bunch of pixels. Basically I want Windows and its drivers to handle all the rendering, and I want access to the output.

Comment: The output goes over a cable to a monitor.  Who says it exists anywhere in memory?

Comment: Well that's why I'm asking.

Comment: If your App uses back-buffering then thie image is stored in the memory. You can also use glReadPixels , render to texture, or even Screen-shot windows desktop or even target window by WinAPI all depends on many things like target fps, do you have access to source code or it is 3th party App/module, what kind of rendering are we talking about, do you have access rights, etc ...

Comment: @Spektre sounds like you have an answer to share :)

Comment: @nebuch yes I did such tasks before but the answer depends on the details I mention so first some more specs are needed to clarify from the OP author side...

Comment: @Spektre Well, to be honest I'm not sure. I was hoping to get insight on how to accomplish this. I definitely prefer not to go through the drivers at all, but instead get access to the frame from the Linux host. I guess this would only be possible if I have access to the output from memory, since the Windows host will be using the GPU itself, and I don't think I will be able to access it.

Comment: @stark, it should be written into some memory of the VGA controller, otherwise the latter won't be able to generate a usable/stable picture on the screen. Please see the Framebuffer on slides #2 and #18 here -- looks like it's Write-only (at least for nVidia GPUs up to nv40): https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis565/LECTURES/Lecture3.pdf#page=18

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not code under **Linux** but in **Windows** (you are running it in emulator anyway) you can use **WinAPI** to directly access canvas of any window or even desktop from **3th** party App. Some **GPU** overlays could be problematic to catch (especially **DirectX** based) but I had no problems with mine **GL/GLSL** for now.

If you got access to App source you can use `glReadPixels` for image extraction from **GL** directly (but that works only for current **GL** based rendering).

1. **Using `glReadPixels`**

   As mentioned this must be implemented directly in the targeted app so you need to have it source code or inject your code in the right place/time. I use for screenshoting this code:

   ```
   void OpenGLscreen::screenshot(Graphics::TBitmap *bmp)
       {
       if (bmp==NULL) return;
       int *dat=new int[xs*ys],x,y,a,*p;
       if (dat==NULL) return;
       bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
       bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;
       if ((bmp->Width!=xs)||(bmp->Height!=ys)) bmp->SetSize(xs,ys);
       if ((bmp->Width==xs)&&(bmp->Height==ys))
           {
           glReadPixels(0,0,xs,ys,GL_BGRA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,dat);
           glFinish();
           for (a=0,y=ys-1;y>=0;y--)
            for (p=(int*)bmp->ScanLine[y],x=0;x<xs;x++,a++)
             p[x]=dat[a];
           }
       delete[] dat;
       }
   ```

   where `xs,ys` is OpenGL window resolution, you can ignore the whole `bmp` stuff (it is VCL bitmap I use to store screenshot) and also can ignore the `for` it just copy the image from buffer to bitmap. So the important stuff is just this:

   ```
   int *dat=new int[xs*ys]; // each pixel is 32bit int
   glReadPixels(0,0,xs,ys,GL_BGRA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,dat);
   glFinish();
   ```

   You need to execute this code after the rendering is done otherwise you will obtain unfinished or empty buffer. I use it after redraw/repaint events. As mentioned before this will obtain only the GL rendered stuff so if your App combines GDI+OpenGL it is better to use the next approach.
2. **WinAPI approach**

   To obtain Canvas image of any window I wrote this class:

   ```
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   //--- screen capture ver: 1.00 ----------------------------------------------
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   class scrcap
       {
   public:
       HWND hnd,hnda;
       TCanvas *scr;
       Graphics::TBitmap *bmp;
       int x0,y0,xs,ys;
       scrcap()
           {
           hnd=NULL;
           hnda=NULL;
           scr=new TCanvas();
           bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
           #ifdef _mmap_h
           mmap_new('scrc',scr,sizeof(TCanvas()        ));
           mmap_new('scrc',bmp,sizeof(Graphics::TBitmap));
           #endif
           if (bmp)
               {
               bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
               bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;
               }
           x0=0; y0=0; xs=1; ys=1;
           hnd=GetDesktopWindow();
           }
       ~scrcap()
           {
           #ifdef _mmap_h
           mmap_del('scrc',scr);
           mmap_del('scrc',bmp);
           #endif
           if (scr) delete scr; scr=NULL;
           if (bmp) delete bmp; bmp=NULL;
           }
       void init(HWND _hnd=NULL)
           {
           RECT r;
           if (scr==NULL) return;
           if (bmp==NULL) return;
           bmp->SetSize(1,1);
           if (!IsWindow(_hnd)) _hnd=hnd;
           scr->Handle=GetDC(_hnd);
           hnda=_hnd;
           resize();
           }
       void resize()
           {
           if (!IsWindow(hnda)) return;
           RECT r;
   //      GetWindowRect(hnda,&r);
           GetClientRect(hnda,&r);
           x0=r.left; xs=r.right-x0;
           y0=r.top; ys=r.bottom-y0;
           bmp->SetSize(xs,ys);
           xs=bmp->Width;
           ys=bmp->Height;
           }
       void capture()
           {
           if (scr==NULL) return;
           if (bmp==NULL) return;
           bmp->Canvas->CopyRect(Rect(0,0,xs,ys),scr,TRect(x0,y0,x0+xs,y0+ys));
           }
       };
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ```

   Again it uses **VCL** so rewrite bitmap `bmp` and canvas `scr` to your programing environment style. Also igneore the `_mmap_h` chunks of code they are just for debugging/tracing of memory pointers related to some nasty compiler bug I was facing at that time I wrote this.

   The usage is simple:

   ```
   // globals
   scrcap cap;
   // init
   cap.init();

   // on screenshot
   cap.capture();
   // here use cap.bmp
   ```

   If you call `cap.init()` it will lock on the whole windows desktop. If you call `cap.init(window_handle)` it will lock on specific visual window/component instead. To obtain window handle from 3th app side see:

   - [is ther a way an app can display a message without the use of messagebox API?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/11920/4709)

   Sorry it is on SE/RE instead of here on SE/SO but My answer here covering this topic was deleted. I use this for video capture ... all of the animated GIFs in my answers where created by this code. Another example could be seen on the bottom of this answer of mine:

   - [Image to ASCII art conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32987834/2521214)

   As you can see it works also for DirectX overlay with media player classic (even Windows PrintScreen function cant do it right). As I wrote I got no problems with this yet.

   **Beware** visual stuff **WinAPI** calls MUST BE CALLED FROM APP MAIN THREAD (WNDPROC) otherwise serious problems could occur leading to random unrelated WinAPI calls exceptions anywhere in the App.

Comment: Thank you! I will probably use WinAPI then. I can see to get anywhere with this, I need to figure out how to get access to this from the Linux side somehow. This is a different topic though. I appreciate your help.