# How do I get a 2D array of pixels from the desktop and/or a window in windows in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, computer-vision, screen

I'm trying to get a 2D array of pixels from an area of the screen of my choice so I can use it in my program. In short, like taking a screenshot without exporting the data into an image.
I would also like to find out do this in both a window and on the desktop. Any help would be appreciated. (I've created an example image to clarify my question. see picture below)
[image]

Comment: you're asking to be recommended libraries? that's called "screen capture" (or screenshot). plenty of answers for that already.

Comment: see [How can I access a graphics card's output directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38549548/2521214) and look the winapi approach ... You can grab either the delected window or entire desktop ...

Comment: @Spektre Wow dude  thanks! this really helps :D